# How to print shortened EPC to a label?

Tags: python, rfid, zpl

I am trying to print a label on a Zebra ZT410 printer and I only want the first 4 and last 4 characters from the EPC code to be printed on the label.

I've managed to print the entire EPC code to the label but I need it to be formatted in order to save space on the label.

```py
# EPC E28011700000020C46CC5D5A
# Desired Format - E2805D5A
```

Is this possible to do using the ZPL commands? Or is there a way we can read in the EPC and format it in Python before printing it to the label without feeding an extra blank label?

Comment: This explains the other question you were asking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically (after literal weeks of research and many useless phone calls to Zebra) this is not possible using the EPC that is assigned to the labels from the factory. However, if you do this ZPL Command

`^RFW,A^FD" + string + "^FS`

whatever is stored in "string" will be converted to hexadecimal and assigned as the labels new EPC and then you can do whatever formatting/manipulation you need to do in order to shorten the EPC and get it printed to the label.